# Remotley control a media players playlist without interupting the current video

Tags: video, android, playlists

Hi I tried using VLC player's web-interface to  change the playlist while my daughter watched it on another computer.
Unfortunately it's useless and only allows to stop start and move up and down the playlist you already have.

I would like to be able to change a playlist on a media player without interrupting the full screen playing of the current content, is there player that does this?

I tried streaming but the formats I am playing didn't seem to stream very well.

UPDATE: Ok I would be very happy if I could just update a playlist file and have the player reread it (as long as the player keeps playing the current track it the list)

UPDATE:
LPChip's suggestion is good but If someone could tell me an android remote that can actually move the tracks up and down in the now playing playlist that would be great!

There is a paid windows 8 app that does this but I would really like android!

Answer (score 0):

You need a program called [XMBC](http://xbmc.org/). I think that's what you're after.

Comment: Can you explain what I would need to control one Windows machine from another?  I just want to add stuff to the playlist of the remote machine without disturbing the video playing.

Comment: Don't know if this is outdated http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=118584

Comment: Ok Theres a Windows 8 remote it seems http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=XBMC_Remote_(Windows)